# Theory of addition and a predicate that recognizes powers of 2

Tags: lo.logic, nt.number-theory

What is the complexity of the theory of addition (Presburger arithmetic) augmented by a unary predicate that recognizes powers of 2?

Comment: Hi David. Are you familiar with the work of Richard? It is not exactly on Presburger arithmetic, so it may not be relevant. In any case: Denis Richard, "All arithmetical sets of powers of primes are first-order definable in terms of the successor function and the coprimeness predicate", Special volume on ordered sets and their applications (L'Arbresle, 1982), Discrete Math. 53 (1985), 221–247. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The theory of the natural numbers with addition and $x\mapsto 2^x$ is decidable.
One reference is the Cherlin-Point paper "On extensions of Presburger arithmetic".
It can be found on Francoise Point's webpage:

http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~point/papiers/cherlin_point86.pdf

Comment: Dave: How do you get around the fact that $\times$ is definable?

Comment: @Andres et al.  I made silly mistake writing the preamble to my question.  But Dave Marker's answer corrects my mistake and answers my question.  Thanks!!

Comment: I've edited my mistake out of the question now! (One could define multiplication if one had  $2^{(\cdot)}$   and  $a^{(\cdot)}$   provided $a$ equals a power of  $2$.)

Comment: Oh! Of course. @Dave: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: And thanks Andres for also for your reference, but I haven't chased it down yet.

Comment: @David: I don't quite see how multiplication can be defined from $2^{(.)}$ and $a^{(.)}$ as you said. Could you clarify?

Comment: I certainly couldn't have meant what I wrote, and I don't remember now (yet) what, if anything, I actually had in mind at the time, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps what I meant was nothing more profound than that one could define multiplication merely among powers of 2.