# What is known about first order logic of $\mathbb{N}$ with + and a unary predicate?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, decidability, theories-of-arithmetic

In "Weak Second-Order Arithmetic and Finite Automata", Büchi claims that the first order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ with + and a predicate for recognizing powers of 2 ($Pw_2$) is expressively equivalent to the weak monadic second order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ with successor via the translation $\sum_{i \in X} 2^i \leftrightarrow X$.

His proof, however, is wrong. Büchi claims that:
$$E(x,y): Pw_2(x) \wedge \exists u, v: [(y=u+x+v) \wedge (u < v) \wedge [v = 0 \vee 2x \leq v]]$$
is an expression of "$x$ occurs in the representation of $y$ as a sum of powers of 2".

Büchi then goes on to speculate on the expressive power of the first order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ with + and a unary predicate $P$, bringing in a result from Putnam's "Decidability and Essential Undecidability" that if $P$ is "is a square", then the theory is undecidable.

I'm very curious about the case where $P$ is "is a power of 2": is Büchi's theorem false or just proved incorrectly?

But I'm also curious about the general case. Have there been any breakthroughs on this problem since Büchi's time? Is there some unary predicate $P$ that does make this first order logic expressively equivalent to the regular languages?

Comment: [Büchi arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_arithmetic) is not quite the same, but you can find a lot of information there.

Comment: I am curious about the history of how this mistake got corrected into Büchi arithmetic, but I'm more interested in the specific case of various unary predicates; this is what Büchi is interested in in "Weak Second-Order Arithmetic and Finite Automata".

Comment: I just found A. L. Semenov's "On Certain Extensions of the Arithmetic of Addition of Natural Numbers" (1980), which seems to address this exact question. I'll answer my own question if I can make sense of it.

Answer (score 6):

We have results on two sides.

**Languages with addition and exponential functions are weak.**

The first order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ with addition and the function $x\to 2^x$ admits quantifier elimination in the language expanded to include $0$, $1$, $x \le y$, $\max(x-y,0)$, and a predicate for each $n$ expressing divisibility by $n$. This is explained in a [paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Efrancoise.point/papiers/cherlin_point86.pdf) of Cherlin and Point, also referred to in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52433/theory-of-addition-and-a-predicate-that-recognizes-powers-of-2). So neither that language nor the language replacing exponentiation with $Pw_2$ can define all regular sets.

**Languages with addition and polynomial functions are strong.**

For any polynomial, the language with addition and a predicate for that polynomial's range is strong enough to define any arithmetic set.

I don't have a reference at hand, but the idea is that if we can recognize the range of a polynomial of degree $n$, we can also recognize the differences of its consecutive values, which are the range of a polynomial of degree $n-1$, so we will be able to recognize the range of some quadratic. If that quadratic is $ax^2+bx+c$, then we can implicitly define $Q(y)=ay^2+by+c$ as the unique element of the quadratic's range which differs from the next element by $(2y+1)+\cdots+(2y+1)+b$, with $a$ additions of $2y+1$. Finally we can implicitly define $x$ times $y$ as the unique $xy$ for which $$Q(x+y)+c=Q(x)+Q(y)+xy+\cdots+xy$$ now with $2a$ additions of $xy$. From this we can define all the arithmetic sets.

**Other functions and languages**

Contrary to what I originally thought, we can't conclude much just from the growth rate of a function.

- The function given by $f(x^2+y)=3^{x^2}2^y$ for any $0\le y\le 2x$ is superpolynomial (and increasing). Since $z$ is a square iff $f(z)$ is odd, the language $(+,f)$ allows defining all the arithmetic sets.
- The function $g(x)=x+\lfloor \log_2(x)\rfloor$ is polynomially bounded, but $(+,g)$ has the same limited expressive power as $(+,2^x)$.

Maybe there will be a simple function which gets exactly the regular sets, but it won't be polynomial or exponential.